# generate N random numbers with X digits such that the difference(the numbers subtracted from top to bottom) is positive

Tags: random, language-agnostic, difference

I am trying to generate N random numbers with X number of digits such that the difference is always positive.

The best way I could think to do this was to generate N numbers

`10,11,30,49,50` then sort them, `50,49,30,11,10` and find the difference `-50` and if it's negative, like in this case, I would do the whole process over again.

As you can imagine, this is a very brute force way and is slow. Is there a better way to do this?

N and X are a maximum of 5 if that helps.

In case this is not clear,

What I need, is to generate a set of numbers. then when you subtract all those numbers, you get a positive answer. In my example the random numbers I generated were 10,11,30,49,50. I know that the best way to get a positive number is to subtract the biggest number from the smallest. so i ordered them from biggest to smallest. 50,49,30,11,10 then subtract them and i got -50 (a negative number) So i have to start over until i get something like 90,20,30,10,11 which when sorted gives me 90,30,20,11,10 which is 19( a positive number) when everything is subtracted and I can stop

I also don't mind if i have to do it a few times, but I want to keep the number of attempts to a minimum

In other words, I am seeking to generate a series of numbers where the maximum value minus the sum of all the others is always positive

Comment: Perhaps I'm being exceptionally dense, but I don't understand what you're asking.  Can you explicitly explain what you mean by "the difference" (the difference between what and what else?) and how you calculate -50 for your set of numbers.  Also, what role did sorting play?  You start with an ordered set of values, and end with a reverse-ordered set.  Why?

Comment: @pjs I was probably just not clear enough. What I need, is to generate a set of numbers. then when you subtract all those numbers, you get a positive answer. in my example the random numbers I generated were `10,11,30,49,50`. I know that the best way to get a positive number is to subtract the biggest number from the smallest. so i ordered them from biggest to smallest. `50,49,30,11,10` then subtract them and i got -50 (a negative number) So i have to start over until i get something like `90,30,20,11,10` which is 19( a positive number) when everything is subtracted and I can stop.

Comment: Still not seeing a good explanation of what, specifically, you subtract from what.  Subtraction is a pairwise scalar operation:  A - B = difference.  What are your A's and your B's, and how does that yield -50?  Also, in your expanded explanation you say "the best way to get a positive number is to subtract the biggest number from the smallest."  It's been a while since I learned subtraction, but I'm pretty sure that subtracting a big value **from** a small value yields a negative number, not a positive one.

Comment: @pjs in this example 90-30-20-11-10 = 19 and 50-49-30-11-10 = -50. i have to subtract all the numbers from the first to the last. ordering them from biggest to smallest gives me the best chance of getting a positive number. I said positive because I am trying to keep all the numbers above 0. sorry for my poor phrasing

Comment: In other words, you're seeking the maximum value minus the sum of all the others.  In that case, order doesn't matter, since the sum of the other values is the same regardless of their ordering.

Comment: @pjs ahh yeah. that is a much better way to put it. Again, Sorry for my really poor phrasing. I am learning as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just generate a number with a random method based on Fibonacci sequence.

In Fibonacci sequence you generate a number based on the previous ones. If you want a random positive number, just generate a random number and add it to the last one, this will always fulfill your requirements.

I made a snippet in python

```
import random

number_list=[]
r_number=0
while(r_number < 100):
    b_number=random.randint(1,10)
    r_number += b_number
    if r_number<100:
        number_list.append(r_number)
print(number_list)
```

And the results:

First execution:

```
[4, 14, 22, 24, 26, 28, 29, 34, 35, 36, 46, 48, 51, 56, 64, 72, 79, 89, 98]
```

Second execution:

```
[7, 13, 19, 27, 34, 35, 39, 43, 45, 48, 52, 58, 68, 74, 83, 86, 88, 93, 99]
```

The advantage of this method (which can be quite better if you optimize a bit the code) is that the complexity is O(n) (linear) rather than whichever sort algorithm you use.

I hope i have solved your doubt
And finally, a personal opinion: The best sorted set is an already ordered set.

Edit 1: I saw that you needed the maximum number to be bigger than the sum of the others, and that is a easy variation.

```
import random

number_list = []
r_number = random.randint(1, 10)
LIMIT=1000

while r_number < LIMIT:
    sum_ = sum(number_list)
    r_number = random.randint(sum_, sum_ + 10)
    number_list.append(r_number)

if number_list[-1] > LIMIT:
    del number_list[-1]

print(number_list)
print("Last element minus the rest equals",number_list[-1] - (sum(number_list) - number_list[-1]))
```

Results

```
[3, 4, 7, 21, 37, 72]
0

[9, 19, 38, 74]
8

[4, 4, 11, 20, 47, 96]
10

[4, 5, 10, 26, 55]
10
```

I just tried setting LIMIT to 1e99 and also timing it:

```
Last element minus the rest equals 7

real    0m0,023s
user    0m0,020s
sys     0m0,000s
```

with plenty of output as you can deduce from this

```
./test.py |wc -c
17109
```

Which counts the chars given by the output of the program. In this case, really long integers.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work exactly. If I find the difference of all your numbers I end up with a negative number. The goal is to take the numbers generated, subtract them from top to bottom and have the result be always positive. I'm going to play with the idea you provided though. I think it's a good start

Comment: This is perfect! exactly what I needed

Comment: Nice :D The thing is just checking each time that the next element to append is bigger than the sum of the list. You can randomize it or whatever.

Comment: How does this meet the number of digits requirement?  In the example, it looked like all of the values were supposed to be two digits.  I guess I'm *still* not understanding the problem specification.

Comment: Number of digits the n variable, its just a matter of having numbers between 0 to (10^n-1)  which would be the limit

Comment: The subject line of the question says "generate N random numbers with X digits," so no, n shouldn't be the number of digits.  And if results should have 2 digits, for example, then values 0 through 9 should be excluded.

Comment: @pjs you are right about that. I made some modifications to his code to make sure it fits the number of digits and the number of numbers I needed. (I used kotlin though)

Comment: Its a matter of adjusting a bit. Being m>n , taking m as  the maximum number of digits. Then 10^(n+1) would be your start point and your limit would be 10^(m+1)-1. If you just wanted a concrete number of digits, being m>0, you would just set n=m-1 
For the N random number limit just add a condition to the number of items to append to your list that exits the loop when required.

Comment: @trenixjetix thanks! that was very similar to what I did. great answer

Comment: Just a word of warning- if anyone who uses this cares about any properties / the distribution of their random numbers (uniform, crypographically secure, etc.), this method will destroy any of those properties of your initial rng. Compared to the brute force method in the original question, this is more restrictive and less uniform.